# issues with jsf after jelastic tomcat server.xml configured

Tags: tomcat, jsf, jelastic

After host is configured by modifying tomcat server.xml in jelastic cloud. jsf page **example.com/abc.xhtml** is working but **example.com/emp/abc.xhtml** is not working, showing jsf source code

Comment: There are about a dozen Q/A about jsf showing the source, so with extensive elaboration on causes. Please read them and see what applies to you... And does it work locally on Tomcat? I would assume it does since you explicitly state jelastic in the title (but you should tag it jelastic to then)

Comment: Rupesh Kumar! In order to help you, we need more information about Jelastic and Tomcat versions you are running on. Example of your server.xml would be useful too.